# IIS8 - Add a virtual application followed by language keyword in multilingual site

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-8

We have a situation in IIS8 to add a virtual application followed by language keyword in a multilingual site. For an example, following are the site links that we wanted to add 'tickets' as a virtual application followed by language code.

https://www.abcd.com/en-sa/tickets

https://www.abcd.com/en-ae/tickets

https://www.abcd.com/ar-ae/tickets

In general, virtual applications will be accessed right after the root domain - https://www.abcd.com/tickets but requirement is slightly different here. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two approaches:

One is to **add a virtual directory in IIS**, for each language level and point that to a single implementation. In the code, you can check the language from the URL and set the culture based on that

Example:

- https://www.abcd.com -> points to single site in IIS
- In that site, add en-sa and other langauges as virtual directory, all pointing to single directory on disk.

The other approach would be to **use ASP.NET routes in a single application**, where URLs don't need to actually exist.

Comment: Thanks for your quick update. Will try above solution and provide a feedback soon..